# How do i restart NGINX daemon Process in linux server if a website hosted on the same server fails to load?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, nginx

I have a website which is hosted on a linux server running on ubuntu 20.04 . Sometimes the website fails to load & it is causing downtime in production as well and it works if nginx process is restarted .
So How do i write a script in python or shell script to restart nginx process only if the website goes down with a http code - 502 ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend looking into the root cause of your issue - what is causing the nginx process to fail? Is your server starting a different process and running out of memory? Tools like [ntop](https://www.ntop.org/) can help here.

Secondly, to automatically restart the nginx service when it goes down, you can edit the `nginx.service` file by running `sudo systemctl edit nginx` and adding the snippet:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
```

This will ensure that if the process fails, it will restart automatically. This being said, I highly recommend looking into the root cause first in order to avoid issues in the future.

Comment: can we have a shell script or python script which will help me to achieve this task as well ?